# Send mail stored in a variable

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a simple table(MyEmail) in SQL with some emails that need to be sent, for example:

```
ID  Email
1   name@yahoo.com
2   something2@yahoo.com
3   name3@google.com
4   something4@yahoo.com
```

I made a stored procedure(GetAddress) to collect them so I can later store them into a variable:

```
 SELECT  Email
 FROM dbo.MyEmai
```

I need help with the C# part of the code:

```
var MyEmails = new List<Email>();
                    SqlCommand cmdEmails = new SqlCommand("GetAddress", connection);
                    SqlDataReader rdEmails = cmdEmails.ExecuteReader();
                    while (rdEmails.Read())
                    {
                        MyEmails.Add(new Email() { MyEmails = rdEmails[0].ToString() }); // as an example 
                    }
```

This code returns list but emails are located bellow WebApplication.MyPage.
Email names.
MyEmails return :

```
WebApplication.MyPage.Email > name@yahoo.com 
WebApplication.MyPage.Email > something2@yahoo.com ...
```

And I need this WebApplication.MyPage.Email removed so only emails will be shown as strings first.

Code that sends emails:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                            client.Port = 112;

                            client.Host = "my-smtp";
                            client.Timeout = 10000;
                            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

                            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myEmail@provider.com", "");


                            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(LocalName, LocalName + MyEmails, "New Mail subject", "This is Email body !");

                            client.Send(mm);
```

So because of this MyEmails has an error : Error    24  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'string'

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `So because of this MyEmails has an error :` Which line of code has that error?

Comment: This:
                            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(LocalName, LocalName + MyEmails, "New Mail subject", "This is Email body !");

Comment: LocalName takes the active directory username and gets his email from table.
So curent user email + emails from table shout be addreses

Comment: can you update the complete code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MailMessage class from .Net does not accepts a List as a valid parameter. Iiterate over your collection creating multiple mailmessage.

The code should look something like  this

```
foreach (var emailadressObject in myEmails)
{
// get your emailadres string from your object..
// Bit confusion using a collection MyEmails and a Property in you mail objetc with MyEmails
var emailadresstring = emailadressObject.MyEmails; 
    var message = new MailMessage("from@me.com", emailadresstring, "New Mail subject", "This is Email body !");
// Do you magic with the mail message
 }
```

Comment: That was it !
TNX MAN!